# Error connecting QuickBooks Web Connector

Tags: qbwc

I'm completely new to QuickBooks Web Connector.  When I try to add my application, I'm presented with a "List of available QuickBooks Point of Sale Servers" from which I'm supposed to select from, but the list is empty???

Answer (score 0):

That list is the results of a qbposservers() call from the sdk. It being empty would imply that you dont have any QBPOS servers running on your local network, or at least none in multi-user mode.

Comment: Also have a look at this for more clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049150/add-an-application-to-quickbooks-web-connector/20776994#20776994