# Add an application to QuickBooks Web Connector

Tags: quickbooks, qbwc

I am trying to add an application to **QuickBooks Web Connector**. I have **QuickBooks Point of Sale 2013 trial** version installed. When an add a .qwc file to the Web Connector, the following happens:

1. Authorize new web service pop up opens - *I grant access to the web service by clicking **ok***.
2. A pop up comes showing the available POS server: *this list is empty. I press **ok***
3. Now I am navigated to a pop up asking some details regarding the company data and server workstation. The pop up contains the following information:

Please enter the computer name of server workstation and company name
I want to connect to the following data : *What to fill here?*
Server Workstation computer name : *What to fill here?*

Can anybody let me know what should be the values for these fields ?

**Note**: Both the Web Connector and QBPOS are installed on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happenning because you have the "trial" version and you need to get a real one and make sure to get a $99 dev license to activate it.

A similar question was answered here:
https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/791000-qbwc-cannot-find-qbpos-what-else-is-required

To sum up all the helpful comments and answers by William Lorfing:

- a) Needed to get a license for devs from
  https://developer.intuit.com/nfr/purchase
- b) Needed to download the
  right version of QBPOS that actually accepts and activates with given
  license.
- c) Needed to have QBPOS running and a company created
  already before attempting QBWC magic.
- d) Needed to be in network mode
  which gets enabled when you use this menu option: "File > Switch
  Company File to Multi User mode" in QBPOS.

Comment: Technically it is because the server is not set to multi user mode. I'm not sure about 2013, 10 could be set to multi user in "trial mode" but not in "free mode"
Obviously getting a full copy is the easiest way to pop it into multi user mode though.